# Java strange reference behaviour?

Tags: java, reference

Lets say I have the following code:

```
public class Collection implements CollectionInterface{

 ElementInterface[] elementArray = new ElementInterface[100];
 int amountOfElements = 0;

 public Collection()
 {

 }

 public Collection(CollectionInterface collection)
 {
  CollectionInterface tempCollection = new Collection();
  while(!collection.isEmpty())
  {
   ElementInterface element = collection.Remove().clone();
   tempCollection.Add(element.clone2());
   elementArray[amountOfElements++] = element;
  }
  collection = tempCollection;

 }

 public void Add(ElementInterface element){
     elementArray[amountOfElements++] = element;
 }

 public ElementInterface Remove(){
  ElementInterface element = elementArray[amountOfElements].clone2();
  elementArray[amountOfElements] = null;
  amountOfElements--;
  return element;
 }

 public boolean isEmpty(){
  return amountOfElements == 0;
 }

 public CollectionInterface clone()
 {
  return new Collection(this);
 }
}
```

Allright, it might seem a bit strange, and it is. But if I use the following code:

```
CollectionInterface collection = new Collection();
collection.Add(new Element("Foo"));
collection.Add(new Element("Bar"));
CollectionInterface collection2 = collection.clone();
```

The first one doesn't contain any elements anymore. How is that possible?

Comment: Don't say JavaScript if you actually mean Java (they have nothing in common).

Comment: ... and please give *real* code, rather than code which fairly clearly won't compile.

Comment: Did I say JavaScript? I didn't mean to? Perhaps autocompletion did it? I'm not sure, sorry for that. And Upvoted Jon Skeet, you're absolutly right. I was editting it, but you are so fast!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not change the reference of an input parameter, as you try in the second constructor.

```
collection = tempCollection.
```

a) is this a syntax error,
b) `collection` is a local variable; assigning to it will change nothing on the outside of the constructor.

Comment: It's not giving a syntax error for me. So you can't change the reference of the paramater of a constructor?

Comment: Then accepting my answer would be appropriate behaviour, I guess. :)

Answer (score 2):

It makes perfect sense. In the constructor, which is called by `clone()` with the original collection as an argument, you use:

```
ElementInterface element = collection.Remove().clone();
```

So you're *removing* elements from the original collection as you create the new one. You don't want to do that...

It's not really clear how you can achieve what you want, given that it looks like your `CollectionInterface` *only* has `Add` and `Remove` methods (which should be `add` and `remove` to follow Java naming conventions) to deal with elements - no way of accessing the collection non-destructively. That's *very* odd for a collection type. Is there any reason you're doing this in the first place instead of using the built-in collections?

EDIT: Ah - I've just had a thought. *Within* the class, you have access to the internals of the collection you're building... so you can destructively copy the elements *from* the collection you're given by calling `Remove` (as you are now) but then when you've built your array, you can use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < amountOfElements; i++)
{
    collection.Add(elementArray[i].clone2());
}
```

... which will put the elemnts back again. This is *horrible* though...

Comment: That’s actually not the whole deal here; he’s trying to use the constructor argument as a return value.

Comment: @Bombe: It's not clear what you mean. I see no indication of what you're describing...

Comment: He’s moving the elements from the given collection into the temporary collection while he clones them (cloning them twice in the process), and at the end of the constructor he’s trying to assign the temporary collection back to the original.

Comment: Ah yeah you're right about that. But that's why I'm using the temporary collection. And then the `collection = tempCollection` code "adds" it back to the origional collection (the one in the argument)

Comment: @TimoWillemsen: What makes you think that would work? That just changes the value of the parameter *variable* - it doesn't change anything to do with the *object* that the variable referred to before. Why are you removing items in the first place?

Comment: Well, I actually thought that would change the original object as well, but if you put it like that it totally makes sense it doesn't. 

And why I'm removing them, it's a school exercise. This are all the methods I have available, and we HAVE to use the copy constructor. I'm struggling to find a way to implement it.

Comment: @TimoWillemsen: Are you not allowed any other methods in `CollectionInterface`, like ways of finding out the size and accessing an element by index? Basically this doesn't look anything like normal code you'd write in real life... can you tell us the details of what you've been told to do?

Comment: Yeah sure, there's one more method in the interface, and it's the size. But it's useless because all I have is this "random" access by the remove method. There's no function defined to access it by index. That makes some sense too, because I have to create a set (so no linear data type) (I'm just using a linear implementation by using the array)

Comment: @TimoWillemsen: No, not being able to access the elements without removing them does *not* make sense in any collection interface I've used :) Anyway, see the bottom of my edited answer for a potential solution. It's pretty ghastly though.

Comment: Yeah I know!! that's how I've implemented it now too! Can you believe we're learning this in university :P

Answer (score 1):

You can just implement the Clone method as follows:

```
public Object Clone() {
    Collection rv = new Collection();

    for (ElementInterface element : elementArray) {
        rv.Add(element.clone());
    }

    return rv;
}
```

You could easily implement this in the constructor if necessary.